# Using SymPy subs method when some of the replacing values are omitted

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to write a program using SymPy in pycharm that will take two inputs and print a result after substitute these values in a function. If the user gives only one input I would like to print the function substituted. This is my code

```
x, y =symbols('x y')
some_function = x + y
a = input("Insert first value")
b = input("Insert second value")
s = some_function.subs({x:a , y:b})
print(s)
```

For two values a=23 and b=34 it returns as output 23 + 34 and for only one value it returns  + 34(as it perceives no input as space). By replacing s with `s = some_function.evalf(subs={x:a , y:b})` the output for two values become 57 but for one value I get syntax error. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

The method `subs` works as expected: to replace two symbols, you must have two values that will replace them.

> If the user gives only one input I would like to print the function

That's the logic that goes between getting user input and invoking `subs`: *parse* and *validate* the input before trying to use it. The method `subs`  calls [`sympify`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.sympify.sympify) on `a` and `b`, and handles the possible errors, such as `sympify("")`, by creating a symbol with the name being that string (e.g., `Symbol("")`).  But you want to handle SympifyError differently. Here is an example.

```
try:
    a, b = map(sympify, (a, b))
    if a.is_Number and b.is_Number:   # the user gave numbers, not asdf and qwerty
        s = some_function.subs({x: a, y: b})
        print(s)
    else:
        print(some_function)
except SympifyError:
    print(some_function)
```